# Sending an image from Pi Camera continuously to a display

Tags: raspbian, python, script, picamera

I want to send 6 images per minute from the Pi Camera continuously to any display. Like for say I have the camera that is at my house but I want to send the images to my work computer.

The end goal is to have 4 Pi Cameras and each of them send 6 images per minutes and on the screen that would have a 4 way split screen on the 4 different cameras. Something similar to a security system.

Some thoughts I have is to grab the pipan software and modify it to send them to a display on a continuous loop.

If anyone can help me come up with a python script on how to execute this, it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hello and welcome -- You can do it completely with the help of **Python** or a bit with crontab. What did you do? What's your problem with insight/thought you said? -- If you just looking for a simple procedure with all codes and configuration, ask it here or on the question.

Comment: Hi yes, I'm looking for a simple procedure with all codes and configuration. I'm just beginning with Python and haven't thought of a way to execute this.

Comment: Hello again, you should split the project into some steps. At first, you need to catch the picture of the camera. Next, send to picture to an unknown place. I have an idea, you can fire up a web server and check the webserver to download the files OR send the pictures to email address. If you want to send the pictures directly to your computer, you need a static IP address on the destination. So, what's your decision?